# Should I upgrade to Castle Windsor v2?

Tags: .net, castle-windsor, ioc-container

We are evaluating to upgrade Castle Windsor Container to Version 2, which was released in May this year. By this time I would expect the community to have made some experiences about the new release...

My main concerns are:

- Is it worth the effort to upgrade to v.2? (any major important new functionality or bug fixes?)
- Is the migration smooth or are there some pitfalls and things that are not backward compatible?
- Is there a performance improvement?

Cheers, Jacob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is worth the upgrade.
A lot has changed since RC3, including many bugfixes, addition of fluent registration API etc.
I don't know about any big perf improvement, but do you have any performance problems with Windsor?

There were no breaking changes as far as I know, but it's best to just pull Windsor down, upgrade and see if all your tests pass.

Comment: I don't have any specific performance problems with Windsor but we are optimizing across the line, and are investigating if we can get a quick gain here.

Answer (score 1):

It requires .Net Framework 3.5, this is what is holding me back to upgrade to the newest release for a few projects that are still running on Windows 2000 machines.

Comment: Well for the projects I did the upgrade, everything went smooth. But I'm still working with the xml-files and aren't using the new fluent/lambda api.